# Where I did mistake in query SQL (UNION ALL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to use `UNION ALL`, but got an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') GROUP BY Product_id' at line 13

How to set correct alias to UNION tables and in result GROUP BY?

Example by [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39ddc2/42)

Comment: You are messing up the derived tables aliases. [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39ddc2/65) works

Comment: Queries that are being unioned together do not need table aliases - only the derived table (the end result of the two unioned tables) need an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the right query structure, UNION/ALL does not require alias however the Derived table will.

```
SELECT
  Product_id,
  sum(Total) as sumOfTotal
FROM ((SELECT
  b.Products_idProducts AS Product_id,
  COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total
FROM products_has_colors a
RIGHT JOIN products_has_colors b
  ON a.Colors_idColors = b.Colors_idColors
  AND b.Products_idProducts <> a.Products_idProducts
WHERE a.Products_idProducts = 1
GROUP BY b.Products_idProducts)

UNION ALL

(SELECT
  b.Products_idProducts AS Product_id,
  COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total
FROM Products_has_ProductComposition a
RIGHT JOIN Products_has_ProductComposition b
  ON (a.CompositionId = b.CompositionId
  AND b.Products_idProducts <> a.Products_idProducts)
WHERE a.Products_idProducts = 1
GROUP BY b.Products_idProducts)) mytable
GROUP BY Product_id;
```

Comment: So, I forgot this `...) mytable...`?

Comment: removed t1 and t2... then call the derived table to something like mytable

Comment: How to SUM(Total) in each sub-queries, and get result value in parent? So I need to COUNT fount rows in two sub-selected and return this in parent SELECT for grouped `Product_id`

Comment: just need to add sum(Total) sumOfTotal from the top.

Comment: Do you mean: `sum(Total) AS sumOfTotal`? It does not work, because I exclude `b.Products_idProducts <> a.Products_idProducts`. So I need to get this only for `a.Products_idProducts = 1`

Comment: the initial OP was all about the error on the grouping... if you other agenda you might want to raise another OP.

Comment: So, I need to get `SUM(COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total + COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total)` from both sub-queries for `a.Products_idProducts = 1`.

Comment: Yes, but may be you can say something about my sub-question

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to return SUM of rows from sub-queries for  condition `a.Products_idProducts = 1`

Comment: which subquery? sorry I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: Look please: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ef285/62 It works, but it looks awful. I do addition two selects in main select.

Comment: that's the only way you can do it. so your code looks fine to me

Comment: I think two selects are redundant in main select, because I count rows in LEFT JOIN, but can not return  it

Answer (score 0):

Your alias is in the wrong spot, and you have some parentheses you don't need. 
You need to alias the entire `UNION` query like this:

```
SELECT product_ID
FROM (
  SELECT BLAH
  UNION
  SELECT BLAH2
     ) as t1
GROUP BY product_ID;
```

In your case it should be this:

```
SELECT Product_id 
FROM (
  SELECT b.Products_idProducts AS Product_id, COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total 
  FROM products_has_colors a
  RIGHT JOIN products_has_colors b 
  ON a.Colors_idColors = b.Colors_idColors AND b.Products_idProducts <> a.Products_idProducts
  WHERE a.Products_idProducts = 1 
  GROUP BY b.Products_idProducts

  UNION ALL

  SELECT b.Products_idProducts AS Product_id, COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total 
  FROM Products_has_ProductComposition a
  RIGHT JOIN Products_has_ProductComposition b 
  ON (a.CompositionId = b.CompositionId AND b.Products_idProducts <> a.Products_idProducts)
  WHERE a.Products_idProducts = 1 
  GROUP BY b.Products_idProducts
      ) as t1
GROUP BY Product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong positioon for table name alias  (t1) assign

```
SELECT Product_id FROM (

  (SELECT
       b.Products_idProducts AS Product_id
       , COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total 
       FROM products_has_colors a
       RIGHT JOIN products_has_colors b  ON a.Colors_idColors = b.Colors_idColors 
          AND b.Products_idProducts <> a.Products_idProducts
      WHERE a.Products_idProducts = 1 
      GROUP BY b.Products_idProducts) 

UNION ALL

  (SELECT 
        b.Products_idProducts AS Product_id
        , COUNT(b.Products_idProducts) AS Total 
        FROM Products_has_ProductComposition a
        RIGHT JOIN Products_has_ProductComposition b ON a.CompositionId = b.CompositionId 
          AND b.Products_idProducts <> a.Products_idProducts
          WHERE a.Products_idProducts = 1 GROUP BY b.Products_idProducts) 
        GROUP BY Product_id)  t1
```